# SQL Query for appending rows into destination using SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have Created a SSIS Package for Importing the Records from One Table to Another table . It is Working Properly But In Source table records are increasing on regular basis . Therefore I am executing package regularly . In Package Before inserting New rows I truncate the records from Destination table then Executing Package .

```
        SQL TASK -1 

        Truncate table "OLE DB Destination"

        SQL TASK -1 

        CREATE TABLE "OLE DB Destination" (

           "ZZCOIL_APPR10" NVARCHAR2(20),
           "ZZSTORAGE_LOC10" NVARCHAR2(15),
           "ZZDETAIL1" NVARCHAR2(40),
           "ZZTOTAL_QTY" NUMBER(7, 2),
           "ZZNOTE1" NVARCHAR2(100),
           "ZZNOTE2" NVARCHAR2(100)
                                           )
```

But I don't Want that solution , I want to insert Only Remaining Records which are not present in Destination table .

Comment: So how do you know what data is "new"? For example, does the source table have columns like `CreateDate` and `UpdateDate`? Does it have a primary key value that increments for each new row? What about rows that are not new, but where the data has been updated? How can you identify from the existing data that something changed? If the source has none of those things, are you able to add them? And are the source and destination both SQL Server?

Comment: Table is having One More column ID <Primary Key>  and I have Also Date Field (record Date) ,So Can how can I trace by using one of them .

Answer (score 2):

you need a lookup transformation.

You will have something like this:

[image]

so your component will have the lookup query as "select ID from DestinationTable" for example and you will match them by ID. All the IDs from source that are not found on your destination table will be sent to the "Lookup No Match Output" path, and then you insert them

There are several example on how to use this component over the internet. [Here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2010/02/09/ssis-snack-configuring-an-ssis-2005-lookup-transformation-for-a-left-outer-join.aspx) is one

Comment: I've never used this approach myself, how does it perform with a lot of rows (say, tens of millions)? And presumably this method can only handle new rows, not changed rows?

Comment: Depending on the quality of your source data, you may also have to perform an aggregation to eliminate any duplicate keys

Answer (score 0):

you can use table difference component in ssis.....